# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty}a\log n-\sum_{k=n^a+1}^{n^{a+1}}\frac{1}{k}=0$ for each integer $a\geq 1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, harmonic-numbers

I believe that for each integer $a\geq 1$
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\log\left(n+\frac{1}{n^a}\right)\right),$$
where $\gamma$ is the **Euler's constant**, when I've use an idea that I've read in a paper.

First, I compute

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{n}{n+\frac{1}{n^a}}\right)=0,$$
because 
$$\log\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{a+1}}{n^{a+1}+1}\right)=\log 1,$$
where $a\geq 1$ is a fixed integer; secondly I write 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\log\left(n+\frac{1}{n^a}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n^{a+1}}\frac{1}{k}-\log\left(n^{a+1}-1\right)+a\log n-\sum_{k=n^a+1}^{n^{a+1}}\frac{1}{k}.\tag{1}$$
Then when I take the limit as $n\to\infty$, previous formula finally shows that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a\log n-\sum_{k=n^a+1}^{n^{a+1}}\frac{1}{k}=0.$$

> **Question.** Are rights my computations? Can you give a different proof of 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a\log n-\sum_{k=n^a+1}^{n^{a+1}}\frac{1}{k}=0,$$
>   when $a\geq 1$ is a fixed integer? **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If previous asymptotic is obvious from standard results please add a comment.

Comment: Note that $(1)$ it is not true. There is a sign error inside the log and the sums don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\mbox{Note that}\quad \sum_{k\ =\ n^{a}\ +\ 1}^{n^{a + 1}}{1 \over k} & =
\sum_{k = 1}^{n^{a + 1}}{1 \over k} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n^{a}}{1 \over k} =
H_{n^{a + 1}}\ -\ H_{n^{a}}
\end{align}

where $H_{m}$ is a *Harmonic Number* which can be expressed in terms of the *Digamma function* $\Psi$. Namely, $H_{m} = \Psi\pars{m + 1} + \gamma$. $\gamma$ is the *Euler-Mascheroni constant*. Then,

\begin{align}
\sum_{k\ =\ n^{a}\ +\ 1}^{n^{a + 1}}{1 \over k} & =
\Psi\pars{n^{a + 1} + 1} - \Psi\pars{n^{a} + 1} = 
\Psi\pars{n^{a + 1}} + {1 \over n^{a + 1}} - \Psi\pars{n^{a}}
- {1 \over n^{a}} 
\end{align}

In this expression we used the *Digamma Reccurrence Formula*
$\ds{\Psi\pars{z + 1} = \Psi\pars{z} + {1 \over z}}$. The $\Psi$ *asymptotic behaviour* is given by:

$$
\Psi\pars{z} \sim \ln\pars{z} - {1 \over 2z} + \mathrm{O}\pars{z^{-2}}
$$

and

\begin{align}
\sum_{k\ =\ n^{a}\ +\ 1}^{n^{a + 1}}{1 \over k} & \sim
\ln\pars{n^{a + 1}} - \ln\pars{n^{a}} + \cdots = a\ln\pars{n} + \cdots
\end{align}

The *'remaining terms'* $\ds{\cdots}$ go to $0$ when $n \to \infty$ such that

$$
\color{#f00}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
a\ln\pars{n} - \sum_{k\ =\ n^{a}\ +\ 1}^{n^{a + 1}}{1 \over k}}}
= \color{#f00}{0}
$$

Comment: But $\log(n^{a+1})-\log(n^{a})=\log(n)$ so the limit it is $\infty$ if $a>1$. Am I wrong?

Comment: I vote up yours answer, and I am waiting about the discussion, very thanks much both @MarcoCantarini

Comment: Very thanks much for details as to use the recurrence and the asymptotic behaviour for the digamma, and draw attention in one of my question.

Comment: @user243301 It's nice it was useful for you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake. Using Abel's summation we have $$S=\sum_{k=n^{a}+1}^{n^{a+1}}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=n^{a}+1}^{n^{a+1}}1\cdot\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n^{a+1}}1\cdot\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n^{a}}1\cdot\frac{1}{k}=\int_{n^{a}}^{n^{a+1}}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t^{2}}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function. Since $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor =t+O\left(1\right)
 $ we have $$S=\log\left(n^{a+1}\right)-\log\left(n^{a}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{a}}\right)
 $$ $$=\log\left(n\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{a}}\right)
 $$ so $$a\log\left(n\right)-S=\log\left(n^{a-1}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{a}}\right)\rightarrow\infty
 $$ if $a>1
 $. If $a=1
 $ we have $$\log\left(n\right)-S=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
 $$ so the limit is $0$.

Comment: Very thanks much @MarcoCantarini and good week.